# Prerequisites for reading "Automorphic Forms and Representations"

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, fourier-analysis, modular-forms

I am hoping to read (at least the first chapter of) "Automorphic forms and Representations" by D. Bump.
As per the introductions, prerequisites are "basic knowledge of algebraic number theory, the representation theory of finite groups, and of Fourier analysis on locally compact groups (Pontriagin duality). Moreover, we assume the existence and basic properties of Haar measure on locally compact groups."

I think my algebraic number theory is up to par but I am not familiar with any of the other prerequisites, apart from having done basic courses in measure theory and functional analysis.

I am looking for texts on the above topics, especially on this flavour of Fourier analysis, that cover what I'll need to understand modular and possibly the basics of automorphic forms, not much more.

Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't need representation theory of finite groups for the first chapter...

Comment: @PeterHumphries That's good to know, thank you. What about the analysis though?

Comment: It's good to know a little Fourier analysis, and be very sharp on your complex analysis